# Use Push Notifications for Angular JS in Laravel 4

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-4, push-notification

I am building a simple app with `Laravel 4` as backend, `Angular JS` as frontend and `MySql`.

So far, i am using long polling for any update in database, for this i have to fire `$http` request from client to server after every 5 minutes.

I need something like **`Push Notifications`** which notify a client server that there is an update in database from server side.

I've searched a lot of things but just found **`Push Notification`** for Android and iOS only.

Is there any Library or Method available to implement **`Push Notification`** for `Angular JS` in `Laravel 4`?

Help Please, It would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this package helps? https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification

Comment: i already go through this package but i found that this is for iOS and android. it uses GCM ( Google Cloud Messaging ) for android in which needs Android 2.2+ version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution would be to use [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebSockets). I suggest using [Ratchet (WebSockets for PHP)](http://socketo.me/). There is also the problem of WebSockets [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets) which you need to take into consideration (but that can be overcome by using the [websocket.js polyfill](https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js)).

Comment: How much is this reliable? and any other options for this?

Comment: Who uses this(Ratchet)?